# Finding anagram using array list

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm trying to find if two string are anagrams of each other:

```
void anagram(String a, String b) {
    List<Character> bcopy = new ArrayList<Character>();

    for (int i = 0; i < b.length(); i++)
        bcopy.add(b.charAt(i));
    if (b.length() == 0 || a.length() == 0) {
        System.out.println("Exit");
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++) {
            char temp = a.charAt(i);
            if (bcopy.contains(temp)) {
                System.out.println("match found" + temp);
                bcopy.remove(temp);
            }
            for (char j : bcopy) {
                System.out.println("Values" + j);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I keep getting an out of bounds error at the remove() line. Can someone please tell me how I reach the array bounds when I'm searching by the object availability? What am I missing here?

Comment: did u try debugging and see the state of your variables?

Comment: I see that I'm getting an error only when the two strings have the same characters in them.

Comment: Thanks but I'm using contains. Where have I used ==

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is you're using the `int`-argument version of `remove()` since the `char temp` is being treated as an `int`. Here's a workaround:

```
bcopy.remove(Character.valueOf(temp));
```

---

By the way a better way to test for anagrams would be something like:

```
char[] c1 = a.toCharArray();
char[] c2 = b.toCharArray();

Arrays.sort(c1);
Arrays.sort(c2);

return Arrays.equals(c1, c2);  // true -> anagram, false -> not anagram
```

Comment: Aaah, thanks! Have been breaking my head over since morning!! Thanks!!

Comment: Thanks, again. I've never thought of doing it that way!

Comment: Oh yes, wanted to but it won't let me before 9 minutes. But will.

Answer (score 1):

there is another algorithm which might be more suitable to the task. it computes the letter frequencies for strings of equal lengths.
 for simplicity i assume that the set of all characters involved can be represented in one of the common 8 bit codepages.

```
void anagram(String a, String b) {
    int    freqa[256], freqb[256];

    if (b.length() == 0 || a.length() == 0) {
        System.out.println("Exit");
        return;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < b.length(); i++) {
        freqa[(int) a.charAt(i)]++;
        freqb[(int) b.charAt(i)]++;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
        if (freqa[i] <> freqb[i]) {
            System.out.println("Exit");
            return;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("match found: '" + a + "', '" + b + "'");
}
```

Comment: Sweet. Thanks for the other solution.

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem with your code. You are removing the items from a list however the loop is running 'n' times is the string length is 'n'.

So if item is removed from the list and the loop count reaches a number which Index is removed from list it will give the exception. You can keep a count instead of removing the items. I modified your code little bit which is working fine now.

Please check

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

class Anagram{
void anagram(String a, String b) {
    List<Character> bcopy = new ArrayList<Character>();
    int count=0;

    for (int i = 0; i < b.length(); i++)
        bcopy.add(b.charAt(i));
    if (b.length() == 0 || a.length() != b.length()) {
        System.out.println("Two strings are not anagram");
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++) {
            char temp = a.charAt(i);
            if (bcopy.contains(temp)) {
                //System.out.println("match found" + temp);
                //bcopy.remove(temp);-- Here list size was reduced but the loop was constant, because list size is less than a.length() now it was giving error
                //System.out.println(c);
                count++;
            }
        }
        if(count==a.length()) {
            System.out.println("Two strings are anagram");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Two strings are not anagram");
        }
    }
}
}

public class Test1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Anagram a=new Anagram();
        a.anagram("abs", "ass");
    }

}
```